# Cups - How to find the status of a particular job

Tags: command-line, printing

Using lp to print a document to printer Zebra on a remote print queue, the job id is returned such as "Zebra-1234".  How can I check the result/status of that particular print job?

Answer (score 0):

```
lpstat
```

is the first tool I would think of to find active and pending print jobs.

If you don't find the particular id in the output, then it has either completed successfully or manually removed with the

```
lprm
```

command.